# Node server is not waiting for oracle db response and re-executing the request method

Tags: sql, node.js, node-oracledb

I have a node server, which is running (first connecting to oracle db) SQL procedures. If SQL procedure is small (completed within 2 min form oracle db) then it is fine. Means **oracle db will send response to node server and then it is sending the response to angular** in front end.

But when procedure is very big and it is taking time around 10 to 15 min, then node is not waiting for 15 min and **re-executing the request method** (in back side oracle db is executing the procedure and it is getting completed properly). Since Angular is also not waiting for response (when node server take more than around 2-3 minute), it is throwing error (no response from node server ).

So my question is , why node is **re-executing the request method**, why not it is waiting for oracle db connection response (node should wait for 15 min if procedure execution is taking 15 min).

Let me know if someone have answer for it.

Comment: Sounds like a db driver issue.  You might want to follow up with the writers of the npm package you are using to connect.

Comment: What are you using for the web server that Angular is talking to? Can you verify if it's calling the code that uses the driver a second time? Have you considered using WebSockets between Angular and Node.js to avoid having to wait? Also, the driver now has built-in support for Continuous Query Notification. You could use this like WebSockets between Node.js and the DB. https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#cqn Consider creating a table to track the status of the job and using CQN to monitor that table from Node.js.